# What will happen If I remove {{Content_for_header}} from shopify page?

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid, pagespeed-insights

I'm new to Shopify and have been trying to optimise the performance for two days, but I've failed because the `{{content_for_header}}` object returns too many scripts (JavaScript). Now that I've removed `{{content_for_header}}` from one page, my page speed has improved. But I'm not sure what kind of scripts are returned by these objects or what effect they will have on the entire website if I remove them permanently.

Could you please tell me whether I should remove this? And what effect will these scripts have?

Second, can you tell me what the purpose of these scripts returned by the `{{content_for_header}}` object is and where I can learn more about their functionality? Or can I add attributes like defer to these scripts?

Comment: {{content_for_header}} append all the scripts from Shopify and 3rd party apps that used script asset api to add scripts and style for there apps.

Comment: If you remove or comment the code, then the store is not working properly and creates issues with core functionality and app features.

Comment: But these third-party apps are slowing overall performance; how can we get rid of them, or can we use a technique to ensure that they have no effect on page speed?

Comment: 3rd party apps are optional to enhance the functionality of store using unique features, if you think it impact the store performance simply remove or not use them.

Comment: If I look through the Shoipfy API documentation, it is not clear how I can remove these third-party apps. and also shopify documentation instructs " You shouldn't try to modify or parse the content_for_header object because the contents are subject to change, which can change the behaviour of your code."   What should i do?

Comment: APPS are installed and uninstall from the backend admin panel, if you have access to do the same.

Comment: It looks like this into backend left hand side. https://prnt.sc/6sxAcSDp8kap

Comment: I know there is an option, but all of the apps that the client has installed are required. I received confirmation from the client twice.

Comment: So you need to compromise on one end, either on performance or feature.

Comment: Can we add defer attribute to scripts returned by the content_for_header object?

Comment: You add the same using liquid logic, but need to have some logic related to liquid code. but some time deferred code does not work due to loading position changes while the page is loaded.

Comment: Can you explain little more? I shall be thankful to u in this act of kindness

Comment: Do something like this https://prnt.sc/s-UJs3nWzV2u